# Convert the output of dtype to type

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have an array and I want to covert the value which is a string to the type of the a.
Is there a way to do it besides something like this: type(a[0][0])(value)?

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0]])

value = "1"

type_a = a.dtype
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your original approach you could use:

```
a.dtype.type(value)
# 1
```

You can also create a scalar array:

```
np.array(value, dtype=a.dtype)
# array(1)
```

If needed to have a python object:

```
np.array(value, dtype=a.dtype).item()
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy array can be quite useful. You can use the approach

```
np.array([value], dtype=type_a)[0]
```